# Missing template file in Magento causing invoicing not to work

Tags: php, magento, error-handling, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I keep recieving the following error Magentos system.log whenever I try and invoice a pending order.

```
2014-02-21T12:52:40+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/sales/order/view/giftmessa   ge.phtml
```

When I click to view/invoice a pending order the order details won't popup instead it just gets stuck as if the page has half loaded and then throws this above message into the error log.

Also, the above error message has been copy and pasted directly from the error log and the spaces in giftmessage.phtml are indeed there (no idea why).

The location the error message is pointing to doesn't exist in Magento and nor does it seem to exist in any of the extension on the site, so I'm not sure where that's coming from.

What I have done is check sales.xml for potential errors although I can't seem to find any.

Here a link to sales.xml if anybody wants to look:

http://pastebin.com/SJ5BwXie

I've also downloaded the same version of Magento and replaced the default files, again, didn't work.

Here is a giftmessage.phtml (without spaces) in a different location:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/giftmessage.phtml

And lastly I have tried copying the above file and adding it to the non-existent directory which also doesn't work with or with spaces.

Link to site: http://bit.ly/1mAxK2a

I'm really stuck on this one and would appreciate and help :)

Comment: There may be several steps to debug you error, however the 1st thing i would try would be going to Admin area, then SYSTEM>>CONFIGURATION>>SALES-SALES>>GIFT OPTIONS. There i would turn off all the gift options to see if the order is still hanging.

Comment: I would start by looking into app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/*.xml files if anyone has "giftmessa   ge" (with spaces) in it. If there will be none then you can search in app/code (maybe some class/observer changes the template)

Comment: Hey @Zefiryn I had quick look and couldn't immediately see this but after using `grep -r -H "giftmessa " *` and found exactly that, one of the .xml files had three spaces as described above. However after a fixing this, cache refresh, server reboot and deleting /var/session/* the problem still persists just without an error message instead. Now when I try to invoice each time this pops up in the log: `DEBUG (7): Connected..`, any idea why this is? Also, @Rounder thanks for the advice but everything is already deactivate and it's still happening.

Comment: Can you paste entire new message from log?